# ObjectMapper - Failed resolution

Tags: java, android, jackson

I try to create ObjectMaper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

But I get such an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView;
```

My dependencies for jackson are:

```
 compile files('src/main/java/com/lib/jackson-databind-2.8.0.rc1.jar')
 compile files('src/main/java/com/lib/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar')
 compile files('src/main/java/com/lib/jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar')

06-15 23:25:04.006 15270-15270/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.amazon.mysampleapp, PID: 15270
                                                                    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView;
                                                                        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.<clinit>(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:36)
                                                                        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:271)
                                                                        at com.mysampleapp.LambdaCommunication$1.onPostExecute(LambdaCommunication.java:83)
                                                                        at com.mysampleapp.LambdaCommunication$1.onPostExecute(LambdaCommunication.java:35)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.4.0_91a7518cef352f6da21a099de420fed4059e9bc5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-picasso-2.5.2_6e50860c1bbe51d4462abf6273a8011df62c50c3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-jackson-databind-2.7.5_1da8a6c005ebd2d4810934e0d0306594c424ff98-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-jackson-core-2.7.5_f12c1f305c1bfd5ae99f43e42cbf99cc997b952a-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.4.0_94ce70faa5545fd8df05785350bb8ceb61b8baa6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-22.2.0_5696fe352c5a829b51d016275400d35b6cedfc12-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-gson-2.2.4_4bdf16c588ee034599c4d23163c8cca82363c4cb-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-wearable-7.8.0_5be987072685244bad2636421690886ce351a4c0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-wallet-7.8.0_b18f7a3b5eb20869cae98cc1ead5d5aa4b8a8b78-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-vision-7.8.0_1681401c9fac4c6c77bbbf4d484022296ece2e67-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-safetynet-7.8.0_0fedf1e586967c3f4b56aefcc919635e9820ce91-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.amazon.mysampleapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-plus
```

EDIT 2:

Those 3 lib works:

```
compile files('src/main/java/com/lib/jackson-databind-2.7.5.jar')
    compile files('src/main/java/com/lib/jackson-core-2.7.5.jar')
    compile files('src/main/java/com/lib/jackson-annotations-2.7.5.jar')
```

Comment: are you sure the stack trace points to this line? JsonView is used via annotation and that error doesnt seem to relate to the ObjectMapper. Can you post more details/full stack trace

Comment: Looking at their github jackson-databind-2.8.0.rc1 depends on jackson-core-2.8.0.rc1 and jackson-annotations-2.8.0.rc1.

Comment: I changed those 3 libraries for the same number: 2.7.5. Sttill the same error. And it is to that line which i said. When I delete there is no error. Full error message I added to my question.